# ask user which column to read in pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set with multiple columns and I would like the user to tell me which col to analyze.
so far I have:

```
file = some_file
col_name = raw_input("Enter column name: ")

cols_used = ["X",col_name]
read_cols = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = cols_used, skiprows = [0,1], name =cols_used)
test = pd.unique(read_cols["X"])
```

for some reason I am not pulling the right cols. When I hard code the col name in everything works fine. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
file = some_file
col_name = raw_input("Enter column name: ")

cols_used = ["X",col_name]
read_cols = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = cols_used, name =cols_used)
test = pd.unique(read_cols["X"])
```

it seams that

```
skiprows = [0,1]
```

cause problems so probably 0 cause to skip column names.... so try this:

```
read_cols = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = cols_used, skiprows = [1,2], name =cols_used)
```

Comment: I tried that, it is still pulling the first and second columns not the columns with names I specified.

Comment: `test = pd.unique(read_cols["X"])` ??? it shouldn't be 
`test = pd.unique(read_cols["X", col_name])`

Comment: no, I am using that as a header later so I just need the "x" col

Comment: I found a work around. I created a dictionary with the col names as keys and col number as values. I then set ` usecols` to the col numbers based on the keys entered by the user. It seems to work well. Thank you!